# Insert error when sending post array to activerecord

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, phpactiverecord

I am using CodeIgniter + phpActiveRecord. I am getting all the records from the `$_POST` array and I want to send that same array to my activeRecord class to insert the data into the DB.

This line doesn't seem to be working but I can't get the error because the page is just blank:

```
Car::create($this->input->post());
```

If the names of the fields are equal to the names of the columns in the table, should it  what I pasted above work?

==========SOLVED========

It is possible to do it, and in the model of the object one can add var `$name_of_the_field_which_you_don't_process = FALSE;`

And that's it.

Comment: What happens if you use $_POST instead of $this->input->post()?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP says in the question itself that this has already been solved. That's not a goof Q n A format.